# JRebel remoting crashing WebSphere on Docker using Eclipse

Tags: docker, crash, websphere, remoting, jrebel

I have configured JRebel remoting mode in an Eclipse maven project on a Windows Machine, and running WebSphere in a Linux docker container.

In JVM args, it's setting

```
-agentpath:/opt/jrebel/lib/libjrebel64.dll -Drebel.remoting_plugin=true
```

When I change source code, jrebel start updating code, and I got the error:

```
2018-02-27 23:32:14.066 ERROR [rebel-CancellableExecutorService-1] c.z.jrebel.remoting.Transaction - [OUT] [tr_36] [Project <maven-module-name>, server websphere] Synchronization failed! Read timed out
com.zeroturnaround.jrebel.remoting.RemotingException: Read timed out
    at com.zeroturnaround.jrebel.remoting.net.RemotingClient.tryMakePostRequest(JRebelRemoting:189)
    at com.zeroturnaround.jrebel.remoting.net.RemotingClient.sendTransactionCommand(JRebelRemoting:147)
    at com.zeroturnaround.jrebel.remoting.net.RemotingClient.commitTransaction(JRebelRemoting:101)
    at com.zeroturnaround.jrebel.remoting.Transaction.commit(JRebelRemoting:487)
    at com.zeroturnaround.jrebel.remoting.Transaction.synchronize(JRebelRemoting:231)
    at com.zeroturnaround.jrebel.remoting.RemoteServer$1.run(JRebelRemoting:56)
    at org.zeroturnaround.common.util.ExecutorUtil$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorUtil.java:153)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

After that, the web application and WebSphere crashed.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the connection failed between the IDE and the WebSphere application server running inside your Linux Docker container.

Firstly, if you are starting your WebSphere server on a Linux machine, you should use the JRebel's agent library compiled for Linux. That is, you should use `libjrebel64.so` in the `-agentpath` argument's path value instead of `libjrebel64.dll`. Using the `.dll` in Linux environment should crash the server on startup. Currently, my hypothesis is that the server does not respond since it does not even start up correctly.

Additionally, please make sure that the server is reachable via the address you entered in the remote server configuration on the IDE side.

If the same issue persists after the previous suggestions, please do reproduce this issue and send us the *jrebel.log* and *jrebel-eclipse.log* files from `~/.jrebel/` directory to support@zeroturnaround.com.

Comment: I am using libjrebel64.so  not libjrebel64.dll. The exception is of the jrebel.log